Есть ли смысл подключать Cloudflare или его аналог?
В последнее время столкнулся с такой проблемой: слишком много на сайт начинает прыгать ботов, особенно есть андройд-боты - которые прыгают менее чем на 1 секунду.
Решил поискать средства борьбы и наткнулся на Cloudflare, вроде норм, но, страна США и соответтсвенно неизвестно что завтра будет - может опять каую-нить санкцию придумают.
Покопал аналоги, потом поанализировал как работает система защиты от ботов и пришел к выводу, что самое действенное - это вести черные списки IP-адресов (по ходу у всех больших кампаний уже целая библиотека таких списков), но вручную их добавлять - это такое себе заняте.
Поэтому сам по себе вопрос стоит ли смотреть в сторону аналогов и если кто уже пользовался из списка аналогов, то может посоветуете проверенного?
Или не стоит тратить деньги на все эти CDN (да, CDN еще и статику повышает, и создает клоны сайтов ужде в нескольких точках, а не в одной) и просто придумать как автоматизировать ведение черных списков?

Для начала логичный вопрос: "слишком много на сайт начинает прыгать ботов" - почему это вообще проблема? Или вы опять какую-то непонятную seo-муть мутите?

Ну, почему сразу муть?) Боты - это все равно проблема. Если бы не было проблем с ботами, то тогда не делали бы подобные сервисы. Или они эти сервисы придумали специально для таких, как я - которые запариваются над тем, над чем не стоит?

Ну в первую очередь такие сервисы придумывают для фильтрации трафика от DDoS-атак. Просто рандомно гуляющие боты - это не DDoS-атака, и с немаленькой вероятностью Cloudflare таких ботов даже пропустит как безобидных

Я просто подключил защиту от D-DOS атак на поставщике VDS - и это никак не помогло. Например, на сайте Wordpres - боты делали заявки. Пришлось их вычислить по IP и кинуть в бан.

А, ну если эти боты спамят - то это уже действительно проблема, но, подозреваю, Cloudflare тут никак не поможет: во-первых, они спамят в том числе с "домашних" IP-адресов, что мешает отличить их от реальных людей, а во-вторых, спамить могут на самом деле реальные люди, которые успешно проходят все проверки на "я не робот", потому что они и правда не роботы. Тут ничего не остаётся кроме как IP в бан кидать

ок, спасибо. А никаких нет сервисов которые вычисляют и в бан кидают, например анализируют по частоте захода на 1 адрес в течении короткого времени? Или надо велосипед изобретать?

Может и есть, но я сам не очень понимаю как это должно работать - на моих сайтах спамеры ходят не очень часто и с разных IP-адресов, иногда с реальным браузером и успешно проходят все капчи (потому что некоторые из них - реальные люди), и в итоге непонятно, по каким критериям фильтровать их от обычных пользователей

Вообще тот же Cloudflare отслеживает "репутацию" IP-адресов, но моим сайтам это как-то не очень помогает - возможно, потому что IP-адреса спамеров постоянно меняются

Если у вас на сайте есть дырища в свободной публикации заявки, заказа, отправки любой подобной формы, то вас и блокировка по IP никогда не спасёт. Нужно искать проблему и решать её. Cloudflare вас тоже никогда и никак не спасёт. Нужно решать проблему в бекенде. Решите проблему - заметите снижение подобных ботов. Боты прыгающие на менее секундный период по сути не должны совершать огромную нагрузку на сервер.
